# how to update request at pre_request with gunicorn?

Tags: python, request, gunicorn

I want to send a object from pre_request to request handler.

```
# config.py
def pre_request(worker, req):
    setattr(req, 'my_message', 'hello,world')

# app.py
import request
...
    @app.route('/')
    def my_handler():
        print request.my_message
...
```

but I got exception with: `*** AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'my_message'`
any wrong with me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# config.py
def pre_request(worker, req):
    req.headers.append({'my_message', 'Hello, world!'})
```

It will be available in a custom `my_message` header.

Comment: is there a way to return HTTP error using from the `pre_request` method without forwarding the request to Flask?